# assignment from incompatible pointer type warnings, and I haven't a cause as float?

Tags: c

assignment from incompatible pointer type warnings, and I haven't a cause as float. What 's happened? please help me thank you.

```
float E2P_read_float(unsigned int addr){
    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char* temp;
    float result;
    temp = &result;
    for(i=0; i<4; ++i)
        *(temp+i) = EEPROM_Read(addr+i);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Which line? What does it say? What does `EEPROM_Read` return?

Comment: `temp = &result;` why assigning float address to `char *` without cast ?

Comment: @นาย ชาเย็น  You need to use explicit casting temp = ( unsigned char * )&result;

Comment: @MaxZoom So that he can read into the memory of `float` one byte at a time.

Comment: `result` isn't assigned to anything and it is returned.  Look into that also.

Comment: Erik W for EEPROM_Read return from

`unsigned char EEPROM_Read ( unsigned int uiAddress )
{
 while ( EECR & ( 1 << EEWE ) );
 EEAR = uiAddress;
 //EECR |= ( 1 << EERE );
 sbi( EECR, EERE );
 
 return EEDR;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely wrong. The meaning of each bit in `float` and `int` is not the same. See [this article](http://www.dummies.com/programming/c/the-real-difference-between-integers-and-floating-point-values/).

```
float E2P_read_float(unsigned int addr){
    unsigned int res = 0;
    for(i=0; i<4; ++i) {
        res |= EEPROM_Read(addr+i);
        res <<= 8;
    }
    return (float)res;
}
```

Except if you have EEPROM reads in float format already, then you should do it like this:

```
float E2P_read_float(unsigned int addr){
    float resFloat;
    unsigned char res[4];
    for(i=0; i<4; ++i) {
        res[i] = EEPROM_Read(addr + i);
    }
    memcpy(&resFloat, res, 4);
    return resFloat;
}
```

But remember that these might have byte ordering problems.

Comment: slezica Thank you.

Comment: You can mark it as correct answer if you are satisfied with answer.

Comment: @tilz0R - The first and 2nd solution should yield the same results. The first one is basically a read and shift.  The second one is store straight into an array.  At the end of the day,  wouldn't provide the same result?

Comment: This is true if data from EEPROM_Read are already representing `int` format. If data from EEPROM_Read are representing float byte orders, then it is not the same as float and int is not the same memory representation.

Comment: Lets say a ROM occupies this binary representation of a float number:00001111000011110000111100001111.  I am not saying this is a float number.  Lets assume it is.  EEPROM_Read() returns 8 bits of info at a time.  So the first return would be 00001111. 2nd return is same thing ...  The above function you provided repackages these 4 sets of bits and make into a float.  So at the end of the day, both of your solutions should yield the same.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: In first example, `res` is type of integer, not float. It won't be the same in fact.

Comment: Whether it is float or integer, both occupy 32 bits (most of the systems).  EEPROM_Read() doesn't know nor care whether it is a float or integer.  All it does is return 8 bits.  The interpretation of these bits is really up to the code: printf("%f" ,, ) or printf("%i", ).  I would think and I would love to test your code and prove that both functions will yield same results given that EEPROM_Read() just returns 8 bits.

Comment: Create a function `EEPROM_Read` which will return `unsigned char` and it should accept int value from 0 to 3 representing which part of byte you want. Then inside EEPROM_Read use `float myNum = 3.0f` and next time use `unsigned int myNum = 3` and try both codes in both examples. Let me know if you get always 3 as output data.

Comment: `float3` and `float4` functions are both reading float values. One with shifting, another without shifting. Here you have your result! https://pastebin.com/3wzzZwTP

Answer (score 0):

I assume EEPROM_Read reads a byte from a given address, and you want to read the binary data from the given address as float. You need to cast the float pointer to the correct type, unsigned char*

```
temp = (unsigned char*) &result;
```